# Paste text verbatim into Sublime without converting tabs to spaces

Tags: sublime-text-3

I am using the Sublime Text 3 beta on Mac OS X 10.8.4. I copied some text from somewhere and I want to paste it into Sublime **exactly as it is** but Sublime seems to be converting tab characters to spaces. What can I do to prevent it from doing this?

Yes, I am sure that the text I copied has actual tab characters. I can see them if I inspect the text in hexdump or TextEdit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some experimenting and found out that I can paste the text verbatim by disabling the "Indent Using Spaces" command under View -> Indentation.

This solves my problem but I don't like to have that feature disabled all the time. What I am trying to do is somewhat unusual. Usually, I like to have it enabled to prevent me from accidentally inserting tab characters into what I am working on.

For that reason, I will see if anyone here comes up with a better solution, and only accept my answer if I don't find anything within a week or so. I am looking for a way to paste text verbatim just one time, without having to change a setting that affects how my tab key works.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into Preferences -> Key Bindings -> User,

I believe that you have to switch the paste and paste_and_indent, like this:

```
    { "keys": ["command+v"], "command": "paste_and_indent" },
    { "keys": ["command+shift+v"], "command": "paste" }
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help. Even with the key bindings all set to their defaults, the `paste_and_indent` command pastes the text, possibly indented, but still with tab characters replaced with spaces.

Comment: Would the `Convert Indentation to Tabs` button, as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575739/how-to-replace-four-spaces-with-a-tab-in-sublime-text-2) solve your issue?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't do anything. AFAIK, that button just converts spaces at the beginning of a line to tabs. I am trying to paste some CSV-like data with some tabs in the middle of a line.